# Pivot table measure inconsistency

Tags: excel, pivot, measure

i am having issues on my pivot table measures.

currently i have 2 pivot tables (one is from A:CD (RANGE) and the other A:CE (RANGE 1)). Reason why i created the 2nd one is because i can't recall the filters i originally have.

i created a measure for RANGE which does =([Sum of Actual Subcont]+[Sum of Commit Lab Costs])/[Sum of Total Floor]

i did the exact same thing for RANGE 1 as well.

The strange thing is that for RANGE 1, it calculates and shows a lump sum figure even though all are exactly the same. what am i doing wrong?

[image: Range]

[image: Range 1]

Comment: Was this created in PowerPivot!?

Comment: no it wasn't. just normal pivot table

Comment: Without actually seeing the data and pivot table config is hard to tell

Comment: Hi Ricardo, the pivot config is default and the first and second data are exactly the same. strange that the first one works but the 2nd one doesnt.